# Decouple backbone.js and jquery

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am evaluating whether I should use `BackBone.js`

I am only interested in the nice structure of BackBone.
But hesitant to use jQuery for the backend (since i have other JS library used).

Is it true that to use backbone we "must" include jQuery as dependency..?

Comment: "Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( >= 1.7.0) or Zepto."  <= http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241831/is-backbone-js-hard-dependency-on-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good question I've asked myself a lot. Basically it's not a problem to exclude jQuery or [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/), but only if you don't need `sync` or any `Backbone.View`.

Backbone uses [`jQuery.ajax`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1204) for syncing, which is hard to create manually ( if you want cross-browser support ), and also DOM events, which are heavily integrated in any [`Backbone.View`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1018). Also there is some jQuery related to [`Backbone.History`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1390).

The problem persist anywhere you need those Backbone features, which is almost the ground Backbone functionality.

Comment: thanks drinchev, unfortunately it's hard to get rid of AJAX call. Is it configurable in Backbone to use other AJAX library?

Answer (score 0):

no backbone isnt dependent on jquery to be used.. its an independent library

*Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( >= 1.7.0) or Zepto.*

[present here](http://backbonejs.org/#introduction)

Comment: You are not right about that. You can exclude jQuery, but your views and sync won't work.

Comment: the question was JQUERY SPECIFIC

Comment: Sharma, thank you for your insight. So you're saying we could use Backbone + Zepto, and all is good in terms of AJAX data fetching?

Comment: by default it uses jquery ajax for fetch/sync but can be overridden and the process is well documented. http://backbonejs.org/#Sync